# Prefetching One-to-Many Relationship django ORM

Tags: python, django, database, orm, prefetch

I am working on an API function right now that would return a list of a users friends as well as all of the references for that users photos. (Although I only need the reference sorted by ord)

Below are my models with the foreign keys.

```
class Personimage(models.Model):
    photo_uuid = models.CharField(db_column='photoUUID', max_length=100, blank=True,
                                 primary_key=True, default='')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Member', db_column='userID', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,
                               null=True)
    ord = models.IntegerField(db_column='ord', blank=True, null=True)
    reference = models.CharField(db_column='reference', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Member(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_id = models.CharField(db_column='userID')

class Friends(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='id', primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    puser = models.ForeignKey('Member', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='puser')
    suser = models.ForeignKey('Member', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='suser',
                              related_name='secondary_friend')
```

So far I was able to do this :

```
friends = Friend.objects.filter(puser=cur_user).prefetch_related('suser')

    for r in friends:
        photos = Personimage.objects.filter(user_id=r.suser)
        united.append({'user_id': r.suser.user_id,
                       'name': r.suser.name,
                       'photos': [photo.reference for photo in photos.filter(user_id=r.suser)]})
```

but as you can image that is incredibly slow as it has to make a call to the Personimage table for each user in the friends list. I know there is a way to do this using prefetch_related or some combination of it and something else but I cannot find how to do it anywhere online or in my experimentation. The closest I got was return just one photo for each of the members in friends.

Comment: Why did you create the Friends model? Wouldn't it be easier to add a friends = models.ManyToManyField('self') to the Member class?

Comment: @RomanB. I created it because i thought i needed the joining table for the many to many relationship. I am quite new to using the Django ORM

Comment: And why do you use db_column for every field? Do you control / create the tables in Django or you are just trying to make an API in Django for existing tables? Are you looking for a solution without having to change the tables or you can modify them to make it work better?

Comment: @RomanB. again that is mroe ignorance when it comes to Django, I am just making an API for existing tables but have full control over modifying them and all of that. So if there is a better way to do it I am open to it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Friends model with a ManyToMany field 'friends' in Member class.
Also I don't think you need the user_id field - you have the default 'id' field, you don't need the alias for that (Django will make it for you).

```
class Member(AbstractBaseUser):
  friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

Then to get the data in the form you wanted:

```
friends = Member.objects.get(pk=cur_user).friend.all().prefetch_related('personimage_set')
united = []
for friend in friends:
  united.append({'user_id': friend.id, 
                 'name': friend.name, 
                 'photos': list(friend.personimage_set.values_list('reference', flat=True))})
```